# Carousel height 100%, carousel-caption align middle and image indicators

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

**PROBLEM**

1. How I can give to the carousel a height of 100 % of the screen?
2. How can I center vertically the carousel-caption?
3. How can I put to the
   same level the carousel-caption and the carousel-indicators (images)?

Can you solve this problem, I tried to solve that but it cant.

Below is the code I have tried:

```css
html,
body{
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-caption{
  top: 60%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.carousel-indicators li{
  height: 72px !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  width: 192px !important;
  background: url(http://ebitfactory.se/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/photo-1465056836041-7f43ac27dcb5-1920x720.jpeg) !important;
}

.carousel-indicators li:hover{
  transform: scale(1.02);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<main role="main">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel" src="http://ebitfactory.se/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/photo-1465056836041-7f43ac27dcb5-1920x720.jpeg" alt="" width="192" height="72"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner h-100">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wnZPRGU.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
        <div class="container align-middle">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wnZPRGU.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wnZPRGU.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks In Advance !

Comment: Is this for presentation purposes or showing something in kiosk mode? The reason for this question is that in normal web pages, I would strongly recommend adding a pause and/or hide button for carousels (and other animation) for accessibility reasons. Moving content is too distracting for certain types of users.

Comment: yes, i want show news on the index

Comment: what it means by 100% `height`, i think you need full height in all screen ?

Comment: what is 3rd point want to say ?

Comment: yes, full screen, actually shows 100% of image, if image height is 5000px, html shows 5000px, maybe removing 'carousel-item img' and give to carousel-item a background image and height 100% and width 100%?

Comment: 3rd point- if i have a 720screen 4 example, carousel-indicators are above of carousel-caption, i want put them at same level?

Comment: i want do the following thing: https://imgur.com/a/u8nZsAH, red is carousel items, green carousel-indicators and yellow carousel caption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to obtain a responsive full-screen carousel it is a food idea to turn your inline images into background images. Bellow I have used a script that "automatically" does that when the page loads.

See what I got by using Bootstrap 4 classes and some custom CSS:

```js
$('#demo').find('.carousel-item').each(function() {
  var imgContainer = $(this),
    bkImg = imgContainer.find('img').attr('src');
  imgContainer.css("background-image", 'url("' + bkImg + '")');
});
```

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0 15%;
}

.carousel-item.active,
.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-item-right {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-item img {
  display: none;
}

.carousel-item h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 0 10%;
}

.carousel-item p {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  margin: 0 !important;
  bottom: 7vh !important;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  height: 20px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  opacity: .8 !important;
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/100/40/?gravity=west") center center no-repeat !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: auto !important;
    top: 67vh !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-inerval=4000>

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="slide-content mx-auto">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wnZPRGU.jpg" alt="">
        <h1 class="display-1 text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipisicing</h1>
        <p class="text-center">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id.</p>
        <div class="text-center">
          <a class="btn btn-md btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="slide-content mx-auto">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wnZPRGU.jpg" alt="">
        <h1 class="display-1 text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipisicing</h1>
        <p class="text-center">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
        <div class="text-center">
          <a class="btn btn-md btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="slide-content mx-auto">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wnZPRGU.jpg" alt="">
        <h1 class="display-1 text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipisicing</h1>
        <p class="text-center">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        <div class="text-center">
          <a class="btn btn-md btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You can write **more CSS**, including **media queries**, to get a result that suits you, on all or most devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the carousel to be full screen set `height: 100vh` and the images as background, otherwise they will be stretched, so:

```
.carousel-item {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/wnZPRGU.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

If you want the captions to be always in the middle of the screen override the css like:

```
.carousel-caption {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Boostrap carousel is not best choice for this problem.
Use 'owl-carousel'. For question 2 and 3 go and learn more about 'position' in `css`.

More information on [Question 1](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-welcome.html)

More information on [Question 2 and 3](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)

Comment: why is better than bootstrap?

Comment: because it's library only for carousel items, bootsrap carousel only add-on for bootsrap library

Comment: i want do the following thing: https://imgur.com/a/u8nZsAH, red is carousel items, green carousel-indicators and yellow carousel caption